# Is their any way, data can be written to CRM applications using Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

This is just for learning purposes. I have worked on ETL where my team loaded data to Salesforce Sandbox provided by our client. It involved few ETL scripts which helped in moving the data to the sandbox for testing. This operation was under taken before production phase. ETL scripts helped in upserting the data from DataStage transformer stage to Salesforce Sandbox stage. 
Is it possible to have ETL like scripts in a Spring Application to write the files in a Salesforce sandbox type setup using Spring Batch?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. You will probably have to write your own writers. But reading bulk of data from a source, processing the data and storing it to a target is exactly what spring-batch is for.

Comment: Hi Hansjoerg, thanks for the answer. Could you tell me how to write a custom item writer for writing data to the Salesforce sandbox? I just need a rough idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is the ItemWriter<T> interface, that has to be implemented. I assume, there is a kind of java-API available which provides the needed features to write into a Salesforce sandbox. You will probably have to manage restart and skip handling, so you will need to get familiar with the ItemStream- Interface as well and the usage of the ExecutionContext. These concepts are not complicated, but you have to understand them.  You should also get familiar with the transaction handling of spring batch: check out https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-1-the-basics/

Comment: Thank you Hansjoerg for this information. Blog is really helpful.